Why most Private Set Intersection(PSI) protocols support only one party to obtain the intersection?
Is there any PSI protocol which supports multi party can obtain the intersection?

In the semi-honest model, the party who gets the intersection can just send it to the other party. In the malicious setting, you can always run two instances of the protocol, exchanging the roles of the parties? I guess for good measure you must add a way to guarantee that the same input is used in both instances, but I assume it should be doable with existing protocols.
